# Devexpress datagrid and form context menu

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, contextmenustrip

When i right click on grid row it shows context menu strip assigned to it for few second and then replace it with form's context menu. How can i make sure that grid's context menu strip remain visible if click is on grid.

Code:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Matches();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Test", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add("A");
        dt.Rows.Add("A");
        dt.Rows.Add("A");
        dt.Rows.Add("A");
        dt.Rows.Add("A");
        dt.Rows.Add("A");
        ContextMenuStrip ctsForm = new ContextMenuStrip();
        ctsForm.Items.Add("Form");
       ctsForm.Opening+=ctsForm_Opening;
        ctsGrid.Items.Add("Grid");
        gridControl1.DataSource = dt;

        gridView1.PopupMenuShowing+=gridView1_PopupMenuShowing;
        this.ContextMenuStrip = ctsForm;

    }

    private void ctsForm_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void gridView1_PopupMenuShowing(object sender, PopupMenuShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView view = (GridView)sender;
        GridHitInfo hitInfo = view.CalcHitInfo(e.Point);
        if (hitInfo.InRow)
        {
            view.FocusedRowHandle = hitInfo.RowHandle;
            ctsGrid.Show(view.GridControl, e.Point);
        }
    }
```

Comment: WPF? WinForms? ASP.Net?

Comment: its winform sorry forgot to mention

Comment: Cant reproduce your problem. Is it your own ContextMenuStrip on Form's which is upcomming or standard ContextMenu from LayoutControl or sth.?

Comment: my own ContextMenuStrip assigned to form

Comment: Which version of DX controls you are using? The described scenario works fine to me. Would you please provide code snippet that demonstrate how the menu and grid are created?

Comment: @DmitryG edited my question with code

Comment: @RahulVasantraoKamble:  adding the following line into Form_Load() method should remove the problem:
`gridControl1.ContextMenuStrip = ctsGrid;`

Comment: @RahulVasantraoKamble I believe using of the Context Menu Strip is a bad approach with XtraGrid. Consider using [customizing the embedded grid's menus](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument709).

Comment: @DmitryG gridControl1.ContextMenuStrip = ctsGrid does not ensure me that menu pops up only if click is on grid row .... so problem continues

Comment: Could you please clarify the exact task? As far as i can see you're  trying to create custom context menu for grid rows and another menu for form. The grid embedded menus should be preserved, and rows menu should be shown for rows only. Am i right?

Comment: @DmitryG you are right if i am using gridControl1.ContextMenuStrip = ctsGrid this it allows menu display even if i clicked on non row area of grid

Comment: @RahulVasantraoKamble I've provided an answer, please review it and inform me whether or not this approach suits your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the possible solution:

```
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Test", typeof(string));
    dt.Rows.Add("A");
    dt.Rows.Add("A");
    dt.Rows.Add("A");
    dt.Rows.Add("A");
    dt.Rows.Add("A");
    dt.Rows.Add("A");
    gridControl1.DataSource = dt;

    ContextMenuStrip ctsForm = new ContextMenuStrip();
    ctsForm.Items.Add("Form");
    ctsForm.Opening += ctsForm_Opening;
    this.ContextMenuStrip = ctsForm;

    ContextMenuStrip ctsGrid = new ContextMenuStrip();
    ctsGrid.Items.Add("Grid Row!");
    ctsGrid.Opening += ctsGrid_Opening;
    gridControl1.ContextMenuStrip = ctsGrid;

    // gridView1.PopupMenuShowing removed at all
}
void ctsGrid_Opening(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {
    e.Cancel = !IsPointInGridRow(gridView1, gridControl1.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition));
}
void ctsForm_Opening(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {
   // some code
}
static bool IsPointInGridRow(GridView view, Point pt) {
    return view.CalcHitInfo(pt).InRow;
}
```

Comment: Can you suggest any way if i want to continue assign ctsGrid to view only not to grid control....?

Comment: @RahulVasantraoKamble view is not a control, thus you can't assign ContextMenuStrip with the gridView. Anyway i suggest you override the view's embedded menu instead of using the ContextMenuStrip with grid control. To override view's context menu use the PopupMenuShowing event. To learn more take a look to the [documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_PopupMenuShowingtopic)